# How to find the sql tables used in a php script?

Tags: php, sql

I recently downloaded a GIT that had no install script or any documentation

is there a quick way to find all of the tables i need to create in the sql db for the script to work?

now i get table not exist error
Error Number: 1146

Table '*****.csport_sessions' doesn't exist

https://github.com/lezardrouge/csport is the script

Comment: Maybe ask the author of those scripts?

Comment: @IkoTikashi This would the only reasonable thing to do. It's quite insane to reverse engineer applications DB schema. Missing tables are easy to find and create but what about the columns and datatypes? It's odd that the author hasn't provided the schema/create table clauses  (at least I didn't find them). Maybe he doesn't really want people using his application or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

Since this it a CI application, I'd probably Ctrl+Shift+F for all occurrences of '->from(' in application/models/ directory..